# Visual Studio Code Unit Tests Environment

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, unit-testing, python-unittest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have the following working directory with my source and tests folders as illustrated

root_folder:

- tower_shell

  - **init**
  - read_files
  - files_processing
- tests

  - **init**
  - test_read_json.py

I want to run the unit test  **test_read_json.py** from my folder **tests** which need the following imports:

```
import unittest
import os
import sys                 
from tower_shell.read_files import read_json
from pathlib import Path
```

The problem is that the file **read_files** (contained in **tower_shell**) folder is also importing a module from **tower_shell** called **files_processing**: \

```
from files_processing import process_hub_sheet, process_tower_sheet
```

Since my working directory is one level up, it raises an error stating that the module can not be imported.

[image]

I tried to add PYTHONPATH variable but the test discovers is not functioning then.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you use absolute module paths also in your source code (e.g. `from tower_shell.files_processing import ...`), or don't you have this code under control?

Comment: Mi idea is not to repeat that command for every single test file.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your meaning. Which command?

Comment: The ones to include absolute paths also in my source code.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand that - I was proposing to change the source code if possible, but you are writing about test files?

Comment: my working directory is at one level top from test and source folders.
My idea is not to touch the import lines from the source code